# Why expect component to be truthy instead of defined

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

This a a general question.

When scaffolding a component with the Angular-cli, it creates the first test itself.

It looks something like this:

```
it('should create', () => {
 expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

How Come it checks if it's Truthy and not Defined? And what is the difference?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: My guess is they don't really thought about that, they just made a test to make the spec file. You can find more [information about the truthy/falsy](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The truthy source code:

```
getJasmineRequireObj().toBeTruthy = function() {

  function toBeTruthy() {
    return {
      compare: function(actual) {
        return {
          pass: !!actual
        };
      }
    };
  }

  return toBeTruthy;
};
```

The defined source code:

```
getJasmineRequireObj().toBeDefined = function() {
  function toBeDefined() {
    return {
      compare: function(actual) {
        return {
          pass: (void 0 !== actual)
        };
      }
    };
  }
```

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/4097718b6682f643833f5435b63e4f590f22919f/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js#L2908

So it's a comparison between `!!actual` and `void 0 !== actual`.

`void 0` is same as `undefined` AFAIK and to me although they are practically the same, `toBeDefined` is a more secure way to check for defined values on some edge cases.

For example:

`expect(0).toBeTruthy()` will evaluate to false/fail

`expect(0).toBeDefined()` will evaluate to true/success

There are more of these cases as [@trichetriche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4676340/trichetriche) mentioned in the comments.

However for your case, it won't make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's greatly appreciated!! :)

Comment: @methgaard Glad I could help :-)

Comment: also note that a `null` value passes `toBeDefined()` but not `toBeTruthy()`

Comment: This is not a solution, only an explanation of the cause of the issue.

Comment: OP is asking about the difference between two methods and why you would use one over the other; I explained the difference and posted a case in which they would differ. Maybe you can clarify what you think the "issue" is @Gonzalo